# How to know which button was clicked in Qt?

Tags: qt

I have 8 buttons in my form (btn1, btn2, btn3, ..., btn8). Each button's text is from a database. I define 8 functions in my database. These are my fields:

```
ID, Text, Active
```

When user presses each button, then I should save the function name in the database. At first, all buttons are hidden. In page load, I read data from database to show the text of function button; if the function button is not active then the button is also invisible.

This is my code :

```
ui->btn1->hide();
ui->btn2->hide();
ui->btn3->hide();
ui->btn4->hide();
ui->btn5->hide();
ui->btn6->hide();
ui->btn7->hide();
ui->btn8->hide();
 QSqlQueryModel *lst=database->getFunctions();
 QString st;

 QStringList btnlst;
 for(int i = 0; i < lst->rowCount(); ++i)
 {
     if(lst->record(i).value(2).toInt()==1)//ACTIVE
     {
         btnlst<<(lst->record(i).value(3).toString());//text
     }
 }
 for(int i = 0; i < btnlst.count(); ++i)
 {
     QPushButton *btn=this->findChild<QPushButton>(st.append(QString::number(i)));
     btn->setText(btnlst[i]);
     btn->show();
     connect(btn,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT(Function()));
 }
```

In that code, I save all active functions in a list and then get the list count. For example, if the length of the list is 3, so the `btn1`, `btn2` and `btn3` should show in my form and the others should stay hidden. Then I connect all of the buttons `clicked()` signal to a slot called `Function()`.

I want to use the text of the button that the user pressed in my form. **How to find which button was clicked, and how to get the text of this button?**

Comment: Depending on what you need to do in Function, `QSignalMapper` http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalmapper.html may be useful

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your slot `Function()`, just retrieve the button you have clicked thanks to [QObject::sender()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/QObject.html#sender), and then you can get the text of that button with [QAbstractButton::text()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#text-prop):

```
void yourClass::Function()
{
    QPushButton* buttonSender = qobject_cast<QPushButton*>(sender()); // retrieve the button you have clicked
    QString buttonText = buttonSender->text(); // retrive the text from the button clicked
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but I used it and It shows me this error: cannot resolve overloaded function 'qobject_cast' based on conversion to type 'QPushButton*'      QPushButton* buttonSender = qobject_cast<QPushButton*>sender();

Comment: @MHM Edited. Missing two parenthesis around `sender()`